# Harmonic series with some numbers deleted for what $\alpha$ is $\sum ' \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a question about a subseries of harmonic series with reciprocals of natural numbers containing a certain digit deleted. I know how to prove that such series is convergent when we delete all $\frac{1}{n}$ where $n$'s decimal representation contains $0,\ 1, \ 2, \ ..., \ 9$. Let's call this series $\sum ' \frac{1}{n}$.

But I don't know how to check for what $\alpha$ is $\sum ' \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$ convergent. I think that for all positive values of $\alpha$, but I'm not sure, that's why I prefer to ask.

Could you help me with that?

Thanks.

Comment: Must $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @L.F. That's what I think. Are you sure it's OK?

Comment: @anorton No, it's just a real number.

Comment: So what happens when you try to apply the proof you know for $\alpha=1$ when $0\lt\alpha\lt1$?

Comment: The proof I know involves dividing terms of the series into gropus, $n$th beginning with $\frac{1}{10^{n-1}}$ Then I show that there are less than $9^{n}$ fractions in nth group and so the sum of the series is less that 90. If I applied it to $0< \alpha <1$ I think there would be more fractions in each group, but would that make the series diverge?

Comment: No, I was wrong. If I applied it to $0< \alpha <1$ I wouldn't be able to use induction to prove that there are less that $9^n$ fractions in each group.

Comment: The number of fractions in each group has nothing to do with $\alpha$, does it?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: So then does the proof for $\alpha=1$ generalize? It's not clear to me what stops it.

Comment: Of course it does. You are right. But $\alpha$ must be greater than  $\log _{10} 9$ in order for the series to be convergent, is that correct?